# I have 2 lists containg two set of points Red and blue. I have one more list containing lines. i have to determine if the line separates

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
import re

Red= [(1,1),(2,1),(4,2),(2,4), (-1,4)]
Blue= [(-2,-1),(-1,-2),(-3,-2),(-3,-1),(1,-3)]
Lines=["1x+1y+0","1x-1y+0","1x+0y-3","0x+1y-0.5"]
ls=[]
red_dist=[]
blue_dist=[]

def sep(ls):
    for line in Lines:
        a=[float(coef.strip()) for coef in re.split('x|y',line)]
        ls.append(a)
        print(a)

    for i in ls:
        for point in Red:
            red_dist.append(float(i[0]*point[0]+(float(i[1])*point[1])+float(i[2])))
        for points in Blue:
            blue_dist.append(float(i[0]*points[0]+(float(i[1])*points[1])+float(i[2])))

    for i in ls:
        for x in red_dist:
            for y in blue_dist:
                if((x>0 and y<0) or (y>0 and x<0)):
                    return True
                else:
                    return False

sep(ls)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Expected output:

```
True
False
False
True
```

Why is my program not looping?

Answer (score 0):

I do think your programming is looping, only nothing visible to the outside happens. Then it reaches the last loop, but this one either returns True, or False. In both cases the function returns without finishing that loop.

Try using print() statements instead of returning the value and a lot happens. It is always a good idea to use some temporary print statements to what is happening inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually looping. You're not able to see it because, whenever the execution reaches the conditionals. Either if or else is always gonna be the case and it's gonna return true or false based on the condition for the first iteration itself.

```
for i in ls:
    for x in red_dist:
        for y in blue_dist:
            if((x>0 and y<0) or (y>0 and x<0)):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

So the output you're seeing is of the first iteration. Simply replace return with a print as follows to observe all your results:

```
if((x>0 and y<0) or (y>0 and x<0)):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: Even if I replace with a print statement, the output is infinite. I am not getting the desired output